# Was Mount Gram another name for Mount Gundabad?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, middle-earth

I have read many articles about the location of Mount gram which mostly suggest it was somewhere between Moria and Gundabad, which got we thinking what if Mount Gram is just another name for Gundabad, we see throughout Tolkiens that he gives certain places multiple names.

So my question is, is there any evidence that  may possible suggest Mount Gram is none other than Gundabad

Answer (score 3):

There's no indication in any of Tolkien's works as to where Mount Gram is, or if it is or is not another name for any other peak.

Further reading: http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Mount_Gram

> The location of Mount Gram has never been established and the mountain could have been anywhere within the northern Eriador region.

Added: In *The History of the Hobbit* John D Rateliff makes the following observation (footnote 1 to Commentary section (ii) of *the End of the Journey*):

> Mount Gram appears only in this context, but this may be merely another name for Gondobad/Gundabad, not least because 'Gram' is a Norse name and thus would seem to belong to the area north and east of Bilbo's home and because the Misty Mountains, which are particularly associated with the goblins throughout *the Hobbit*, also seem to be the mountains closest to Bilbo's home.

This is the only speculation regarding this in any Tolkien-related writing that I am aware of.

Looking further at the chronology of the Third Age, we know that the Battle of the Greenfields took place in TA 2747, whereas the Dwarves cleared out Mount Gundabad in the years from TA 2793 to TA 2799.  Therefore Mount Gundabad *was* populated by Orcs at the time of the Battle of the Greenfields, so it remains a possibility.  However, and in the complete absence of any further authorial comment, all we can do is say that "it might have been the same mountain" and leave it that: everything else is speculation.